# Only last data is fetched from firesbase after refreshing the page with firebase .on()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am experiencing a strange problem with firebase Realtime DB.problem is with a chat component.

```
 componentDidMount(){
  this.renderMessages();
 }

renderMessages(){
rdb.ref("chats/"+this.props.id).orderByChild("time").on('child_added',   (snapshot)=>{
             if(snapshot.exists)
            {
                this.setState({messages [...this.state.messages,snapshot.val()]})
            }

    })
}
```

then map through this state and pass data to other components and **everything works fine on the first run.**

**consoled Object On the first run [ it is an array of objects ]**

```
   0: Object { message: "hello", read: false, sender: "Shan", … 
   1: Object { message: "Hai Shan", read: false, sender: "AashiqOtp", … }
   2: Object { message: "hi", read: false, sender: "AashiqOtp", … }
```

when I go back and re-entered into the component it then it only shows the last object of the array
ie

```
0: Object { message: "hi", read: false, sender: "AashiqOtp", … }
```

what's the issue? can someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

I am using " .once " event listener there are no problems, but as it is a chat component I need to always listen to the event.

Comment: Are you using the `.on` listener anywhere else?

Comment: for this "/chats"  NO ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue related to state not updating fast enough. You should use an updater function, if your new state is based on the old one.

Also, you shouldn't call `this.setState` multiple times in the `forEach` and instead add the whole array at once, to avoid many unnecessary rerenders and issues like this one

```
renderMessages(){
    rdb.ref("chats/"+this.props.id).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            messages: [
                ...prevState.messages, 
                ...snapshot
                    .filter((childsnap) => childsnap.exists)
                    .map((childsnap) => childsnap.val())
            ]
        }))
    })
}
```

Since you changed the event in the question, there is no way to add the whole array at once and you have to use the less efficient method:

```
renderMessages(){
    rdb.ref("chats/"+this.props.id).orderByChild("time").on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                messages: [
                    ...prevState.messages, 
                    snapshot.val()
                ]
            }))
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: it shows snapshot.filter is not a function and same with .map() as the snapshot is an object not an array

Comment: I have no idea how the `.forEach` works in your case then... I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: okay.. i have just removed forEach by replacing **.on('value')** with **.on('child_added')**